# kmm ios simulator service version does not match expected service version error

Tags: ios, kotlin, kotlin-multiplatform-mobile

After creating a kmm application using the wizard from the kotlin-multiplatform-mobile plugin, I tried running the ios simulator and got the error below.

```
kotlin multiplatform mobile java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unsupported Xcode version 12.4, minimal supported version is 12.5.
```

To solve the error I tried updating Xcode, giving me the new error below.

```
CoreSimulator.framework was changed while the process was running.  This is not a supported configuration and can occur if Xcode.app was updated while the process was running.  Service version (776.4) does not match expected service version (732.18.6).
```

Comment: Restart Android Studio, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue, and it was fixed by restarting Android Studio